# ASP.NET: Avoiding creating a View for a model for a Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a doubt.

For a property of a model, `Machine`, I need a dropdownlist with the possible values.

Of course, each element of the `Machine` model can be edited later, so the dropdownlist needs to have the rest of the possible elements so they can be chosen.

**What  I know:**

So far I have created models with Views for these properties, since these classess had also their own properties and was worth it. For example, `Supplier`.

But right now I need some dropdownlist for a properties that, besides providing info for the specific property, there isn't much about them. For example, `Machinecolor`.

**The problem:**

The problem comes I think of how initialize the `Machinecolor` property.

I could create a model, but I don't want/need to create a View just to populate each color.

How can I populate the model directly, without the need to creating a view, and so the values are saved in the _context/model.

Is this a way?:

```
namespace Application.Models
{
public class MachineColor
{
    public MachineColor() {
        //how to insert several values? is this correct?
        ColorDesc = "Green";
        ColorDesc = "Blue"; //(?)
    }

    public static string ColorDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Or do I need to do it thru the **DbInitializer** model? If so, how can this be done if my Database is already created?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry ! What are you trying to do ?

Comment: What you mean by **How can I populate the model directly, only once** ? I am still not able to understand what you are trying to do and where you are stuck at

Comment: @Shyju Sorry, I edited the question. So far I populate my models using Views I constructed but for this particular model an entire view is not needed, however, I don't know how to insert the values of the model into the db/_context so the other models can access to these values

Comment: You create many objects of MachineColor class and set the ColorDesc property values to different colors (it should not be static property) and add to db.MachineColors and Save it, in your Db initializer class.

Comment: Ok, so it must be done inside the DB Initializer class. I believe the DB Initializer executes the first time we run our projects so it creates a first view of our Database, and after that we only update the database thru migrations, am I correct? If I edit it and update the DBInitializer, will the changes apply to the database?